# Python: Getting all NaNs with `skimage.transform.estimate_transform`

Tags: python, transform, scikit-image

I am trying to determine a transformation between two images using `skimage.transform.estimate_transform` but I am only getting NaNs as the transform params, and consequently, all NaNs for a transformed image.

Here's my code:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.transform import warp, estimate_transform
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom

# Get the image to transform
image = zoom(data.camera(),4)[-256:,:]

# Make the source and destination images
dst = np.array([range(i,i+2048) for i in range(256)])
src = np.tile(np.mean(dst, axis=0), (256,1))

# Estimate the transform between the two
tform = estimate_transform('affine', src, dst)

# Transform the input image
out = warp(image, tform)
```

But as you can see, the output is just a 2D array of NaNs. Can any one explain what is going wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE:

I found a great package called [imreg_dft](http://pythonhosted.org/imreg_dft/quickstart.html#python-examples) that does exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`estimate_transform` takes two sets of coordinates (not images) as input, and tries to find a corresponding mapping.  If you want to do dense or sparse registration, you'd either need to try optimizing over, say, a SimilarityTransform, or extract features and find the transform between them (using `estimate_transform`, e.g.).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Though if I don't have features per se to identify in each image as they are just (not necessarily linear) gradients, how can I do image registration? Would you mind providing an example? Thanks!

Comment: For dense image registration, you may want to look at Elastix or SimpleElastix.  If you are only interested in translation, you can try http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.register_translation